# Htmlspecialchars not needed in this case?

Tags: php, security

I am developing an application and I am reading up on implementing security measures.  I set up a class to automatically generate form elements and the class embeds php string variables within html to create the fields.  I noticed, however, that `htmlspecialchars()` was not necessary as I went to implement it.  So I am attempting to pseudo-maliciously turn this:

```
<input type="text" name="email">... rest of html
```

into:

```
<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
```

However, both before and after using htmlspecialchars(), my browser gives me this when I try to edit the frontend html:

```
<input type="text&quot; name=&quot;email&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;
```

Is this just something that is automatically implemented? If so, is this from a PHP update (I thought I found something about it being an update in PHP 5.4)?

Furthermore, can I abandon using `htmlspecialchars()`?

### Edit

More information requested:

```
$this->type = 'text' //what I would normally use
$this->type = 'text" name="name"><br><br>' //my attempt to manipulate the html
$output = "<input type='$this->type' name='$this->name'";
$output .= ... close the tag, etc.
echo $output;
```

Comment: how are you testing make sure you are viewing source as opposed to looking in dev tools or firebug.

Comment: I am using firebug, but other echo statements display as their html form and this one behaves as if I used htmlspecialchars()

Comment: use the browsers view source... dom viewers show how it was interpreted, not always the same as how it is returned.

Comment: viewing the source shows the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this manipulation:

```
$this->type = 'text\' name="name"><br><br>' //my attempt to manipulate the html
```

It should break your HTML, because the delimiters for your attribute value are single quotes, and now they appear in your attribute text as well.

And please make sure not to use any sophisticated DOM inspectors like firebug, but to look at the pure source code that is emitted by your server.

Comment: Your manipulation worked. Htmlspecialchars() fixed the manipulation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The use of `htmlspecialchars` is required whenever you take some text and insert it into some HTML as a string (unless you know that the text won't contain any characters with special meaning in HTML, but even then using `htmlspecialchars` is a good habit to be in).

I can't explain why your *unspecified* input, when run through your *unspecified* code and then run through a browser's parser (with error recovery features), gives you that output.

---

After the question was updated:

```
$this->type = 'text" name="name"><br><br>' //my attempt to manipulate the html
$output = "<input type='$this->type' name='$this->name'";
```

Your attribute value is delimited with `'` characters. Your data doesn't contain any `'` characters, so it isn't going to terminate the attribute value and escape.

Comment: I added details that will hopefully be helpful.